# If button is not pressed again within 10 seconds, send alert

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a button ("check") which starts a countdown that, when in reaches zero, the phone vibrates.  Pressing "check" again turns off the vibration and the process starts over. Pressing "alert" at any time sends an SMS to a pre-designated number.  That is my code so far, and as far as that goes, it's working fine. But I would like to connect these functions so that, once the vibration starts, the user has ten seconds to tap "check" and restart the timer, or else the "alert" function will start, sending an SMS.  How would I go about this? Would I need to make another countdown timer?

**"check" button code so far:**

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                vibe.cancel();
                if (countDownTimer != null)
                    countDownTimer.cancel();

                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerTime * 1000, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long milliseconds) {
                        long minutes = milliseconds / 60000;
                        long seconds = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
                        minsLeft.setText(getString(R.string.minutes) + (int) (minutes) + "  seconds:" + (int) (seconds));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        minsLeft.setText("Are You OK?");
                        long[] pattern = {100, 1000, 100, 2};
                        vibe.vibrate(pattern, 1);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

**"alert" button code** (this would be called if "check" wasn't pressed again):

```html
    public void onAlertClick(View view) {
        Toast sent = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Toast permissions = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please change app permissions in settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


        try {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(getString(R.string.smsNumber), null,
                    getString(R.string.smsMessage), null, null);
            sent.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            permissions.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please only use the android studio tag for general programming questions - it's for questions about the tool itself.

Comment: You've shown a lot of code here, which is nice, but you don't do much to explain the problem with it. Is there an error in logcat? Is something not happening like you expect it to? What did you expect? You'll likely attract more (and better) answers if you provide more detail here.

Comment: @HPierce (and EJoshuaS) I've made some changes to my question and tags. I'm not sure I can make this too much more specific because I have no idea where even to start.  I have, however, made some changes to clarify my question.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

what I would do, is create a dialog fragment when the first timer finishes, then in that dialog fragment have another timer that counts down 10 seconds - if the dialog timer hits 0, then execute your alert method:

(p.s. you can nest this class inside your main class so you can call upon your first countdown timer easier)

```
public static class SessionExpiringDialog extends DialogFragment {
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer2;
    public SessionExpiringDialog() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_dialog, null);
        final TextView sessionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.session_text);
        countDownTimer2 = new CountDownTimer2(11000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long diffSeconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60;
                sessionText.setText("SMS Alert will be sent in: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                onAlertClick(view);
            }
        };
        countDownTimer2.start();
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setMessage("Alert SMS Pending").setTitle("ATTENTION:")
                .setPositiveButton("I'm OKAY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        countDownTimer2.cancel();
                        countDownTimer.start();
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

this code assumes a layout xml exists called res/layout/session_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/session_text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

then to call this code, put it in the onFinish() method of your first countdowntimer:

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            vibe.cancel();
            if (countDownTimer != null)
                countDownTimer.cancel();

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerTime * 1000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long milliseconds) {
                    long minutes = milliseconds / 60000;
                    long seconds = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
                    minsLeft.setText(getString(R.string.minutes) + (int) (minutes) + "  seconds:" + (int) (seconds));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    minsLeft.setText("Are You OK?");
                    long[] pattern = {100, 1000, 100, 2};
                    vibe.vibrate(pattern, 1);
                    SessionExpiringDialog sessionExpiringDialog = new SessionExpiringDialog();
                    sessionExpiringDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    sessionExpiringDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
```

lastly, I didn't see why you're passing a view in your onAlertClick() method, but I went ahead and included it in my pasted code